# Swing: How could I get JInternalFrame treated equally to other components inside a container?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

**Background information:**

I am implementing a visual diagram editor, which consists of

- different complex elements (re-sizable, with title bar, sub-elements) and
- different simple elements (not re-sizable, no title bar, no sub-elements).

All elements are draggable.

I am using JInternalFrame (for complex elements) along with JPanel
(for simple elements) to represent elements of a schematic diagram. There is a container (either a JDesktopPane or a JLayeredPane), which contain
all these elements.

**I have several problems with this concept:**

***Case 1* - The container is a JDesktopPane:**

- JInternalFrames are always above other elements.
- Clicking other elements don't "deactivate" previously active JInternalFrame

***Case 2* - The container is a JLayeredPane:**

- After clicking some elements inside a JInternalFrame, it stays
  "activated" forever.

***Case 3* - JInternalFrame used for everything, but without decoration for simple elements:**

- My custom border *(which is needed when I manually remove
  JInternalFrame's title bar)* is every time replaced by current LAF border, after
  activating/deactivating the JInternalFrame.

I don't get the whole concepts behind activating JInternalFrames anyway.
**If I could make a JInternalFrame not activable at all**, I could
choose ***Case 2*** any would be happy.

Please advice me, what would be an simple and straightforward solution to given problems.

**NOTE: Selection of components and activation of JInternalFrame
seem to be different things.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might misunderstand your problem. Have you tried to look at the setSelected() method of JIF? It seems there are support for method override and vetoable activation events.

**Edit:** Maybe we have some terminological misunderstanding as the javadoc states:

```
/**
 * Selects or deselects the internal frame
 * if it's showing.
 * A <code>JInternalFrame</code> normally draws its title bar
 * differently if it is
 * the selected frame, which indicates to the user that this
 * internal frame has the focus.
 * When this method changes the state of the internal frame
 * from deselected to selected, it fires an
 * <code>InternalFrameEvent.INTERNAL_FRAME_ACTIVATED</code> event.
 * If the change is from selected to deselected,
 * an <code>InternalFrameEvent.INTERNAL_FRAME_DEACTIVATED</code> event
 * is fired.
 *
 * @param selected  a boolean, where <code>true</code> means this internal frame
 *                  should become selected (currently active)
 *                  and <code>false</code> means it should become deselected
 * @exception PropertyVetoException when the attempt to set the
 *            property is vetoed by the <code>JInternalFrame</code>
 *
 * @see #isShowing
 * @see InternalFrameEvent#INTERNAL_FRAME_ACTIVATED
 * @see InternalFrameEvent#INTERNAL_FRAME_DEACTIVATED
 *
 * @beaninfo
 *     constrained: true
 *           bound: true
 *     description: Indicates whether this internal frame is currently
 *                  the active frame.
 */
```

**Edit 2:** Now I re-read your 2nd case. I would say each JIF has its own separated focus/selection environment. You could create a method which traverses all your JIFs and deselects anything in it unless its the component you wanted to be selected.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help. Selection doesn't have to do with JInternalFrame's activation.

Comment: You see, even in the Javadoc it is confusing. They talk about selecting, but the property is named "activated". Note: there is also a property "selected" (which does not apply to my problem). Hmmm, I'm confused...

Comment: I don't get it. Now I've added InternalFrameListener and FocusListener to all JIFs, but non of these listeners receive any events!

Comment: InternalFrameListener works now, my mistake. But I think I'll make the whole thing somehow different. But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

give this a try when you initialize your JInternalFrame=

```
 new JInternalFrame(<your args>) {
          protected void fireInternalFrameEvent(int id){  
               if (id != InternalFrameEvent.INTERNAL_FRAME_ACTIVATED) {
                   super.fireInternalFrameEvent(id);
               }
          }
 };
```

note that looking at the code in `JInternalFrame.setSelected(boolean)`, setSelected and 'actvation' are tied together in process, in that setSelected fires not only property changes for Selection, but also calls  `fireInternalFrameEvent(InternalFrameEvent.INTERNAL_FRAME_ACTIVATED)` as well.